# Stolen phone: Is there any way to get Automatic Call Recorder recordings that were set to be stored in SD card?

Tags: applications, data-recovery

I had extremely important calls recorded of ex-boyfriend threatening my life and admitting to the things he did that I'm taking him to court for. But my phone was stolen recently, and I had only set the app to save the recordings to my SD card.

Is there a  way to retrieve those recordings? Maybe they are saved somewhere I just don't know about?

When I got my new phone I downloaded the same app and these recordings are saved to my Google drive, but old ones aren't there.

Comment: Can you share the link of the app that you were using to record the calls?

Comment: Sorry! I won't be surprised if the answer is no. Unless you took a backup of your SD card, or Google somehow took the backup of that app (but those files are unlikely to be backed up), your chances to get them are almost none.

Comment: Firelord- that's what I pretty much figured, but figured couldn't hurt to ask. Thank you though :)

Comment: Lucky- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appstar.callrecorder&hl=en I'm screwed on retrieving any recordings aren't I?? :'(

Comment: An important thing from the next time, though you would've figured it out already. Always take regular backup of SD card(s), irrespective of whether the files are getting uploaded somewhere or not. Two things are very important: 1) Call recording as you know it, 2) Images and Videos which are irreplaceable moments.